# Copying value from different Excel sheets using some condition

Tags: vba, excel

i need it to check if the value in Col A is equal to Value Col A Sheet 2 then copy the values from Sheet2 to Sheet 1 in the respective rows.

Comment: Show us what you have tried...  We can help you from there.. It is very unlikely you get a complete solution here.

Answer (score 0):

In sheet3 enter:

> =IF(Sheet1!A1=Sheet2!A1,"Equal","Not equal")

[Or check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12436822/3892567)